# SQL Double Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am working on a double dynamic pivot based on 2 columns (HardwarePhase & HardwarePhase_Result).

Using the first result set in the image below, is the raw data that I have.  Each set of 5 items (highlighted in images) are grouped based on HardwareTestCaseID.

The second result set in the image, is the current results that I'm getting from how I've constructed this query.  **Ideally**, the result of the second column would be the same results, but instead it would be grouping the results.

**The grouping is supposed to be based on the HardwareTestCaseID, but however, this is not happening.**

[image: Current Results]

**The results I actually want** are shown here. (There should be multiple rows, but this is just how it should be grouped per 5 entries).

[image: Ideal Results]

**This is the query I am currently using:**

NOTE: The @col variables are built up based on the list of HardwarePhases (P0, M1, M2, M3).

```
select @query = 'SELECT ' + @colsNames + ',' +  @colsResultNames + ', HardwareTestCaseID FROM 
            (
                SELECT HardwarePhase_Result, HardwarePhase, ResultValue, HardwareTestCaseID, HardwareStatus
                FROM #temp4
            ) as x
            pivot 
            (
                 MAX(ResultValue)
                FOR HardwarePhase_Result IN (' + @colsResult + ')
            ) as p 
            pivot 
            (
                 MAX(HardwareStatus)
                FOR HardwarePhase IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) as p2 ';
```

using this table:

```
create table #temp4
(
    HardwarePhase nvarchar(max),
    HardwarePhase_Result nvarchar(max),
    ResultValue bigint,
    HardwareTestCaseID bigint,
    HardwareStatus nvarchar(max),
    Block nvarchar(max)
);
```

Comment: Can you give us some minimal sample data?

Comment: The first half of the first image is the raw data and the second half being the result of my current query.  Would any more actually be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would do it slightly different since you want to PIVOT on two columns.  I would look at unpivoting the data in the multiple columns first, then apply the PIVOT function.  I also would suggest that you start with writing a hard-coded version of the query first then convert it to dynamic SQL - this allows you to get the correct logic.

To unpivot the data, I would use CROSS APPLY so you can convert the pairs of columns into rows at the same time, the syntax would be similar to the following:

```
select col, value, HardwareTestCaseID
from temp4
cross apply
(
  select HardwarePhase, HardwareStatus union all
  select HardwarePhase_Result, cast(ResultValue as varchar(10))
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8d70/3). Your data is then in the format:

```
|       COL |       VALUE | HARDWARETESTCASEID |
|-----------|-------------|--------------------|
|        P0 | Not Started |                365 |
| P0_Result |           1 |                365 |
|        M1 |        Pass |                365 |
| M1_Result |           1 |                365 |
|        M4 |        Pass |                365 |
| M4_Result |           1 |                365 |
|        M2 |     Blocked |                365 |
| M2_Result |           1 |                365 |
```

Then you just apply the pivot function to the data:

```
select M1, M2, M3, M4, P0,
  M1_Result, M2_Result, M3_Result,
  M4_Result, P0_Result,
  HardwareTestCaseID
from
(
  select col, value, HardwareTestCaseID
  from temp4
  cross apply
  (
    select HardwarePhase, HardwareStatus union all
    select HardwarePhase_Result, cast(ResultValue as varchar(10))
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col IN (M1, M2, M3, M4, P0,
              M1_Result, M2_Result, M3_Result,
              M4_Result, P0_Result)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8d70/6).

Once you have the logic down, then convert it to dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col) 
                    from temp4
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select HardwarePhase, 1 union all
                      select HardwarePhase_Result, 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so
                    order by so, col
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' , HardwareTestCaseID
            from 
            (
              select col, value, HardwareTestCaseID
              from temp4
              cross apply
              (
                select HardwarePhase, HardwareStatus union all
                select HardwarePhase_Result, cast(ResultValue as varchar(10))
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8d70/7).  This process gets a result:

```
|      M1 |      M2 |      M3 |      M4 |          P0 | M1_RESULT | M2_RESULT | M3_RESULT | M4_RESULT | P0_RESULT | HARDWARETESTCASEID |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|--------------------|
|    Pass | Blocked |    Pass |    Pass | Not Started |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |                365 |
| Blocked | Blocked | Blocked | Blocked |        Pass |         1 |    (null) |         1 |         1 |         1 |                366 |
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  You broke down the query very nicely piece by piece with great visual help to support it.  The query is working flawlessly.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

```
--This is Just AWESOME. Simplified it for just one table as it's a much more common case (and could not find anything even close to this elegant after trying for hours)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(your_key_column) 
                    from YOUR_ORIGINAL_KEY_AND_VALUE_TABLE
                    group by your_key_column
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT your_row_heading_columns,' + @cols + '
            INTO YOUR_NEW_PIVOTED_TABLE
            from 
            (
              select your_row_heading_columns,your_key_column,your_value_column
              from YOUR_ORIGINAL_KEY_AND_VALUE_TABLE
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(your_value_column)
                for your_key_column in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```